# Unhandled exception using wsprintf

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Below code throws unhandled exception at wsprintf.

```
 #define FRONT_IMAGE_NAME "Image01front.bmp"
 void GetName(LPTSTR FileName)
 {

     wsprintf(FileName, "%s", FRONT_IMAGE_NAME);
 }

 int main()
 {

    GetName(FRONT_IMAGE_NAME);
    return 0;
 }
```

Please let me know why exception is generated at wsprintf.

Thanks.

Comment: What is FileName in main() initialised to?

Comment: Please look at the updated code in my question.

Comment: Also, have a look at the MSDN page for wsprintf. It recommends the use of StringCbPrintf or alike instead. And adds a security consideration to avoid the %s format.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to write from FRONT_IMAGE_NAME to FRONT_IMAGE_NAME. You can't write to something that is not a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

LPTSTR is a typedef. An LPTSTR
actually is a TCHAR*, which depending on whether UNICODE is defined maps to
either char* or wchar_t*.

You need to initialize your LPTSTR to sufficient size for the string you
want to return. You do this in two ways, on the stack or on the heap (with
new):
On the stack:
TCHAR FileName[50];
wsprintf(FileName, "%s", FRONT_IMAGE_NAME);

On the heap:
LPTSTR FileName= new TCHAR[50];
wsprintf(FileName, "%s", FRONT_IMAGE_NAME);
delete[] FileName; // DO NOT FORGET THIS!